# Perl one-liner with -pl command-line options

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I'm running

```
perl -ple '$_=length' datafile
```

The datafile contains the following:

```
algorithm
student government
Fiumichino
```

The result is that it prints

```
9
18
10
```

What do the -p and -l options do? Also, what is `$_`?

Comment: the word in the datafile are all in separate lines

Comment: See the perlrun and perlvar documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_) is the default input and pattern-searching variable. `-p` is a command line switch that puts an implicit `while(<>)` loop around your program, with a print statement at the end. The `-l` switch sets `$/` and `$\` to "\n" (newline) and `chomp`s your input, or in layman's terms, it handles newlines for you.

The diamond operator `<>` is "magic" in that it automatically chooses your input channel. If your script has arguments, it will interpret it as a file name, and open that file and read it. If not, it checks STDIN. In your case, it opens the file "datafile".

What that oneliner does is read each line of datafile and sets `$_` to the length of `$_` (since [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) uses `$_` if no argument is supplied), then prints that number.

You can deparse the one-liner and see what the code looks like:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ple '$_=length' datafile
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    $_ = length $_;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 3):

`-p` causes the Perl interpreter to loop over its input and run the code (supplied via `-e` in this case) once per line, instead of just once total. At the bottom of each loop iteration it prints the line out.

The actual line is read into the `$_` variable, and the contents of that variable are what is printed at the bottom of the loop body, so by changing the contents of `$_` inside the loop, you can change what is output.

The `length` operator with no argument counts the length of `$_`.  So `$_=length` replaces the line with its length before it gets printed.

`-l` just causes the Perl interpreter to remove newlines from input (so they won't be counted in the length values here) and automatically put them back on output (otherwise the output would be jammed together as 91810).

Comment: A bit confused by the edit, @PeterMortensen; lowercase "perl" already means "the Perl interpreter", as opposed to capitalized "Perl" which means the language... that's straight-up Camel jusage.